# How to pass control to the terminal?

Tags: c, terminal, sdl, sdl-2

My SDL program requires the user to type things in sometimes, so how do I send control from the program window to the terminal ready for the user to type without having to manually click on the terminal?

Answers in pure C and SDL2 please.

Comment: I doubt it's possible with pure C & SDL2. Are OS-specific solutions ok for you? If so, what OS?

Comment: You must provide the interface to take input -- generally by implementing a dialog with an input. (good catch @HolyBlackCat - forgot about the sdl event loop.)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If I understand correctly, OP wants the terminal window to become focused, which it apparently doesn't do automatically.

Comment: Yes, I snapped to that after reading your comment.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I didn't mean that stdin wouldn't work. :) The window could appear grayed out since the events aren't handled, yes; but that's not necessarily a problem.

Comment: Well, you brought up a good point. Depending on how the application is running, it may or may not be possible to prompt for input on the terminal. If control is turned over to SDL event loop, then it wouldn't be possible to simply prompt for input back on the terminal that launched the program without implementing an event callback, etc.. However, if the program is running sequentially and just flashing up windows or colors with control returned to `main()`, then the simple I/O would work. Looks like the Wiki has a preferred way [SDL_PollEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin @HolyBlackCat I am using an `SDL_PollEvent` loop, I have never seen an SDL program which mainly has one window for interaction return to main while keeping the program window open so I wouldn't know where to start with that idea. So it looks like it's agreed it's not possible?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is it possible within C and SDL2 to allow users to type in a textbox? Some sort of GUI box which pops up, a user types in the box and clicks an 'okay' and that input is fed to a string? (Not taking into account any downloadable libraries, only the main libraries included with the official SDL pack)

Comment: @User.Flynn Yup, apparently impossible. No, I don't think SDL has that functionality.